# Inherit builtin `str` class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to inherit the str module with custom type, but while doing so gives error.

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __init__(self, word, idx: int=0):
        super().__init__()
        self._word = word
        self._idx = idx


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = MyStr(word='Word', idx=1)
    print(x)
```

This error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/xyz.py", line 9, in <module>
   x = MyStr(word='Word', idx=1)
TypeError: 'word' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

So, How do inherit `str` module with custom parameters.

I have try this method to inherit all the methods and attributes.

```
class MyStr(str):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return str.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, word, idx: int=0):
        super().__init__()
        self._word = word
        self._idx = idx

    @property
    def idx(self):
        return self._idx

    @property
    def word(self):
        return self._word


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ms = MyStr(word='snake', idx=10)
    print(ms)
```

So I am expecting the output as:-

```
Expecting Output:
    Str: snake

But this give this 
    Str:
```

Comment: You need to implement `__new__`, that's what gets called first.

Comment: @jonsharpe I used it ```class MyStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return str.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, word, idx: int=0):
        super().__init__()
        self._word = word
        self._idx = idx``` like this but nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean *"nothing happens"*? You don't get the error any more (which is presumably a good thing)? You might not *see* anything, because your instance looks like an empty string.

Comment: If you don't pass any arguments to `str.__new__` all your `MyStr` instances will be empty strings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  -"nothing happens"- means it doesn't have inheriting any `str` class methods

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? o_O

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am trying to pass custom parameters to my string class which has string and it's index in it's attributes

Comment: Then you should give a [mcve] illustrating that, rather than the old problem you don't have any more, because when I do e.g. `dir(MyStr(word='Word', idx=1))` I see all of the inherited methods as expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have update the question with new code. Can you please help me on that what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That doesn't illustrate the problem you've described, why do you think `ms` doesn't have the inherited methods? As I and @Aran-Fey have mentioned, your usage of `__new__` is building an *empty* string (with some extra attributes). Also note that if `word` is the value you actually want the string to have, you don't need to store it as an attribute.

Comment: You seem to think that assigning a string to the `self._word` attribute will somehow magically turn your `MyStr` instance into that string. In other words, you're doing both inheritance and composition at the same time. You don't need both. Just don't inherit from `str` and save yourself the headache. Inheriting from builtin types is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, @jonrsharpe my only concerns is to add one attribute which holds the index of word Like I pass `MyStr('Word', idx=10)`. so Once I create the instance I will able to access the custom attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a keyword argument for the string's value.  Just use a single positional argument.  The function signature will be MyStr(s, idx=0) where s is the value of the string.

(1) In your implementation of `__new__` do not pass the keyword argument.  `str.__new__` will not know what to do with it.  Both arguments will get passed to `__init__`.

(2) In your implementation of `__init__` just ignore the first argument. It has already been used to initialize the string by the `str.__new__` function.  All you need to do here is to store the `idx` argument in a new variable.

(3) Just get rid of the `.word` property.  You already have a string, so the `.word` property doesn't add anything.

The new instance will behave like a string and will have all the methods of a string.  It will also have the property idx.

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, s, idx=0):
        return super().__new__(cls, s)
        # less good style is: str.__new__(cls, s)

    def __init__(self, s, idx: int=0):
        super().__init__()
        self._idx = idx

    @property
    def idx(self):
        return self._idx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ms = MyStr('snake', idx=10)
    print(ms, ms.idx)
    print(ms.upper())

# Output:
# snake 10
# SNAKE
```

I basically agree with those commenters who advised against doing this on general principles (it's tricky and your code will not be easy to understand for someone else).  But it does work.