# Inheriting from “str” classs

Tags: python, string, inheritance

I am a python newbie and might have asked many stupid questions already, please forgive me. I saw the following python code to sort strings and it works very well. But I can't figure out how it works exactly by myself. I understand that class `Predicate` inherits class `str` and overloads the object's `__lt__` (<) method, which is later used in `sorted` function to conduct the sorting.

```
## code 1 ##
class Predicate(str):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print(self, other)
        return self + other < other + self

list_ = ['3', '30', '34', '5', '9']
sorted(list_, key=Predicate, reverse=True)

output:
['30', '3', '34', '5', '9']
```

However, here is what I don't understand: when I call `Predicate(3)` it returns `"3"`, how this process works? I expect it to be like:

```
## code 2 ##
class MyString(str):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self=str.__init__(x)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self + other < other + self
```

Since I did not use `__new__` or `__init__` method as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531160/inherit-builtin-str-class-in-python). I want to know exactly how the input `3` is passed into class `Predicate()` and how `"3"` is generated and returned in **code 1**? I also try to look into `str` class [source code](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c), but it is in c and may be too hard for me. Could anyone help me with digesting the inheritance of `str` in `Predicate`  and the initialization process? I am very grateful for your help and education.

Comment: Since `Predicate` does not have its own constructor, the constructor of the superclass is used, which is `str()`. And `str(3)` is `"3"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"3"` you see when you call `Predicate(3)` isn't actually the result of the call, it's the `repr` of the result. If you save it to a variable with something like `p = Predicate(3)`, you'll be able to test that `type(p)` is `Predicate`. It has the same `repr` as a string because you haven't overridden the `__repr__` method in the class (and indeed, you don't really need to, since you aren't usually going to keep `Predicate` instances around).

That's also why an integer value is acceptable to construct a `Predicate` in the first place. You're inheriting `str.__new__` (not `__init__`, because strings are immutable in Python), and `str(3)` unsurprisingly constructs the string `"3"`. The `p` instance we create with `Predicate(3)` is *almost* the same as the string `"3"`. It has the same `repr` and most other methods behave the same. But has its own method for handling the `<` operator, which is why it's useful as a sort key.

Comment: could you please let me know where I can find the definition of ```str.__new__```, ```str.__init__``` and ```str.__repr__```. I tried ```help(str)``` and ```dir(str)```, which give a rough description of them rather than the definition. In class ```str``` [source code](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c), I can not even find ```init``` and ```repr```.  Thank you very much.

Comment: The CPython code for strings is pretty complicated, mostly due to the API evolving, but the developers trying to backwards compatibility. The C code that implements `str.__new__` is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8b33961e4bc4020d8b2d5b949ad9d5c669300e89/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L15436). Most of what it does is delegated to other functions though, so you'll be searching all over that file to understand everything. But you really don't need to understand the low-level details of the `str` object to understand what's going on in your code. That's just basic inheritance.